# Need help making a batch file to do certain things

Tags: batch-file, copy

This is hard to word but I will do my best. What I am trying to do is make backups of backups basically. I have several files and folders in FOLDER1. What I want to do is make a batch file that will move my files and folders from FOLDER1 to FOLDER2. At the same time everytime I run this batch file I want it to create a folder in FOLDER2 with the month,day,year,time as the folder name because I am going to be running this batch everyday and I don't want it to overwrite my previous files. Is there anyway to do this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the %date% variable to create a folder name. You can see this with

```
echo %date%
```

which yields 07/02/2012 (on my UK machine; 7th Feb)

To extract each individual component of Day, Month and Year, use a substring %date:~OFF,LEN% where OFF is the zero-based offset to start extracting and LEN is the length of extract, in chars.

Create a folder name into a variable, dest:

```
set dest=%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%_%date:~6,4%
```

You can now move files into this folder:

```
move src %dest%
```

Comment: Ok. But my only issue is that the folder name can't contain "/" marks. any way around that? Thank you for your help

Also can you give me an example so I can visually see it?

Comment: This answer doesn't contain "/" marks, it creates a folder in the convention MM_DD_YYYY. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMIC to get the date/time in UTC format which is suitable for a file or directory name. The beauty of this technique is it is totally locale independent. If you want you can strip off the time zone info as I do below.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set dateTime=%%A
set dateTime=%dateTime:~0,18%
```

The dateTime will have format YYYYMMDDhhmmss.ddd

YYYY = year
MM = month
DD = day
hh = hour (24)
mm = minute
ss = second
ddd = fractional second